# Change Billing address from US to International on virtual products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have a **WooCommerce** shop that sells products in the US only. Is it possible to allow a international country billing address when purchasing a *virtual/downloadable* product.

So when checking-out to purchase a product, it will have the international country not US /states billing fields available.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

So, Basically where you select your country, it should be a country drop-down list, but just for virtual products. See image below

[image]

Comment: can you explain little more what you exactly want to do ?

Comment: Hi, when someone purchases a product (virtual product) I would like them to be able to use a International (i.e Select country) billing address. At the moment it is set to US (country) address only, but on virtual projects I would like them to be able to use an International one as well. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: you still need help? i am ready to solve it .

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to: WooCommerce > Settings > Shipping 
2. choose ship to all countries form Restrict shipping to Location(s).
please check the screenshot :
http://prntscr.com/dw66tl

thanks